# xPages @DbLookup issue

Tags: xpages

I have this code in several repeat controls and computed values

```
 @Unique(@DbLookup(database,view,key,columnnumber))
```

I can see that if "columnnumber" is a categorized column then DbLookup only return first Category.

Today my solution is create another view with this column Uncategorized, but this is bad solution for my customer, and more work for me.

Somebody knows if this is a bug? or is there another solution?

I have Lotus Domino 8.5.3 UP1 and same designer

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

You can get the view entries this way:

```
var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("view").getAllEntriesByKey(key, true);
```

Then you can loop the collection with:

```
var ve:NotesViewEntry = vc.getFirstEntry();
ve = vc.getNextEntry();
```

In the loop, get the column value with:

```
ve.getColumnValues();
```

My understanding is that this will perform better than @DbLookup which - I believe - has similar code underlying it. Fastest way to loop a view is to use a ViewNavigator as Fredrik suggested:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Fast_Retrieval_of_View_Data_Using_the_ViewNavigator_Cache

Comment: Thanks a lot Panu and Fredrik, finally i will use a code similar to this, but I think that there is a bug for DbLookup in this case.

`var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("view").getAllEntriesByKey(key, true);
var list = new java.util.Vector();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = vc.getFirst();
while (entry != null) {
 if (entry.isCategory()) {
list.addElement(entry.getColumnValues().firstElement().toString());
 } 
 var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNext(entry);
 entry.recycle();
 entry = tmpentry;
}
return list;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using @DbColumn instead or a viewnavigator.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use @DbColumn I can't filter result by key. I can write a complex code with a bucle, but I think that performance will be bad

Comment: If you need to filter on a second categorization, I would suggest a view navigation approach with a scoped cache.